# onTriggerEnter not firing when an AI enters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am creating a project in which there are collectibles either the player or enemy AI are able to pick up which will increment the score of whatever picked it up as well as spawn a new collectible. for my player the it works fine but when my enemy moves into what should be the trigger collider of the collectible (which is a prefab instantiated using code if that makes a difference) nothing happens.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Debug.Log ("hihihi");
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        other.gameObject.SendMessage("spawnNewPage"); 
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Start").SendMessage("FindPath");
        other.gameObject.SendMessage("incrementScore"); 
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Start") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").SendMessage("spawnNewPage");
        other.gameObject.SendMessage("FindPath"); 
        other.gameObject.SendMessage("incrementScore"); 
    }
}
```

is what i am currently using on the pickups.cs on the collectible prefab but it doesnt trigger for my enemy. the player is the standard fps controller prefab from unity. is there anything obvious i am missing my enemy doesnt have any colliders or anything on it but then neither does my fps controller so i dont think thats the issue. have double and triple checked all my tags so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: added a characterController to my enemy tank which ended up fixing the issue seems a bit of a dodgy way to do it but at this point it works

Comment: Do you have Rigidbody component attached to your enemy gameobject?

Comment: Did you try just adding a rigidbody to your enemy? If it works for the player you should compare what is on the player object and enemy object to find the difference... I'm 110% certain you do not "fix" this issue with a character controller... Although it may be a solution, I do not think it is right one.

Comment: comparing the player object is what brought me to attach the character controller for it. i found it weird that it wasn't colliding with a rigid body that i did originally have on the object. at the time the fact that it worked with a character controller however dodgy that solution was was enough for me to be able to move on with the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both comments and other answers are correct. You may want to add a rigidbody to your AI, but if you want a custom solution (like collectibles can trigger only and exclusively with player and AI) you may add a particular layer to your AI and set the collider of the collectibles to consider collisions only with player and with "custom layer".

Answer (score 2):

There was a table that showed when collision and trigger events are fired on [docs.unity3d.com](http://docs.unity3d.com). But they have updated the site and now I can't find it. I still have it local. So, here it is.

## Collision action matrix

> Depending on the configurations of the two colliding Objects, a number of different actions can occur. The chart below outlines what you can expect from two colliding Objects, based on the components that are attached to them. Some of the combinations only cause one of the two Objects to be affected by the collision, so keep the standard rule in mind - physics will not be applied to objects that do not have Rigidbodies attached.

### Collision detection occurs and messages are sent upon collision

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╤══════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╗
║           ║ Static   │ Rigidbody │ Kinematic │ Static   │ Rigidbody │ Kinematic ║
║           ║ Collider │ Collider  │ Rigidbody │ Trigger  │ Trigger   │ Rigidbody ║
║           ║          │           │ Collider  │ Collider │ Collider  │ Trigger   ║
║           ║          │           │           │          │           │ Collider  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╣
║ Static    ║          │     Y     │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Rigidbody ║     Y    │     Y     │     Y     │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Kinematic ║          │     Y     │           │          │           │           ║
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Static    ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Trigger   ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Trigger   ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Kinematic ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Trigger   ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

### Trigger messages are sent upon collision

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╤══════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╗
║           ║ Static   │ Rigidbody │ Kinematic │ Static   │ Rigidbody │ Kinematic ║
║           ║ Collider │ Collider  │ Rigidbody │ Trigger  │ Trigger   │ Rigidbody ║
║           ║          │           │ Collider  │ Collider │ Collider  │ Trigger   ║
║           ║          │           │           │          │           │ Collider  ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╣
║ Static    ║          │           │           │          │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │    Y     │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Kinematic ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │    Y     │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Static    ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Trigger   ║          │     Y     │     Y     │          │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Rigidbody ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Trigger   ║     Y    │     Y     │     Y     │    Y     │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╟───────────╫──────────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────────╢
║ Kinematic ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Rigidbody ║     Y    │     Y     │     Y     │    Y     │     Y     │     Y     ║
║ Trigger   ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
║ Collider  ║          │           │           │          │           │           ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╝
```

## Layer-Based Collision Detection

> In Unity 3.x we introduce something called Layer-Based Collision Detection, and you can now selectively tell Unity GameObjects to collide with specific layers they are attached to. For more information click [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).